# Change Insufficient Privileges

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table (based off of a `.csv` file I've been working with) within SQL, but I'm getting the following message:

> SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>   01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
>   *Cause: An attempt was made to perform a database operation without the necessary privileges.

What do I need to change to create the table?

Here is the my code to create the table--then I have a bunch of `INSERT INTO` lines.

```
CREATE TABLE Water_Birth_Consent
(
   NAME        VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL
  ,MRN         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,DATE_SIGNED VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ,EDD         VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ,DEL         DATE 
  ,WB          VARCHAR(5)
  ,study_id    VARCHAR(17)
  ,comments    VARCHAR(42)
  ,EMPI        INTEGER 
);
```

Comment: Request sufficient `CREATE` and `INSERT` rights from your DBA.

Comment: It isn't something you can do as the user that is running the `create` statement - if you could grant yourself privileges it would make them a bit pointless. A privileged user (i.e. a DBA) needs to set your user up properly.

Comment: That may include other privileges - `create index`, `create view`, or whatever other objects you need to create/alter - and they may also need to grant you a space quota on your tablespace(s).

Answer (score 1):

Another user with sufficient privileges (DBA) needs to grant your user the `create table` privilege. This is the command they would run:

```
grant create table to <your-user>;
```

Once you are able to create the table, you won't need any additional special permissions to insert data into the table.

Comment: No additional permissions, but may need to have a quota granted on the relevant tablespace(s) *8-)